# How to write test cases for material UI Multi select & simple select component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write unit test cases for material UI multi select & simple select component in jest Enzyme.
this is my parent component code.

```
<ComponentModal>
    <FilterComponent {...props} />
    <MainFilter {...someProps} />
</ComponentModal>
```

In MainFilter Component I am using multi select & select component like this -

```
                    <MultiSelect
                        multiple
                        native
                        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void =>
                            onChangeMultiSelect(event)
                        }
                    >
                        {data.map((item: any) => (
                            <option key={item.label} value={item.value}>
                                {item.label.replace(/_/g, " ")}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </MultiSelect>
                        <Select
                            options={translatedData}
                            value={selectedData}
                            onChange={(selectedOption: NewOption<string, string>) =>
                                onChangeSimpleSelect("myData", selectedOption)
                            }
                        />
```

I tried to write test case for select component like below -

```
it('my test', () => {
    let btn = wrapper.find(btn);
    btn.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find(ModalPopup).prop('open')).toBe(true);
    act(() => {
        wrapper
            .find(ComponentModal)
            .first()
            .find(Select)
            .first()
            .prop('onChange')('myData', { label: 'All', value: 'All' });
    });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(
        wrapper
            .find(GlobalSearchFilterModal)
            .first()
            .find(Select)
            .first()
            .prop('value')
    ).toBe('myData');
});
```

I don't know whether I did right or wrong although it is not throwing any error. No error but still there is no code coverage. So is the above unit test case is right for the `<Select>` ? and can anyone help me in writing test cases for `<MultiSelect>` ?

Comment: please add some more details

Comment: @UKS I have written all the code here like Component code test cases. What else you need ?

Comment: `let btn = wrapper.find(btn);` where is this button and the handler ?

Comment: <NarrowButton
    icon="mi-icon-filter"
    style={ButtonStyle.Flat}
    label={translateFn!('Filter')}
    onClick={event => {
     event.preventDefault();
     setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    }}
   /> 

The is just a button when you click on it. It just opens a Modal.